# Spammy Referral Traffic on Joomla site

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, .htaccess-configuration

Yesterday I was looking into my Google Analytics and found some spammy refferal sites, which I want to block. Can someone please help in this regard?

Following are Spam sites:

ILoveVitaly.Com
Priceg.com
Darodar.com
BlackHatWorth.com

I found following code, but whenever i place into .htaccess file, site returns Internal Server Error:

## Block Spammy Website Referrers

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer BlackHatWorth.com spam=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer http://blackhatworth.com/marketing/lounge/730430-apple-com-analytics-referral-traffic.html.com spam=yes
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer priceg.com spam=yes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=spam

Come some one share some code to block these domain? I am using **Joomla 3.3.6**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops. Originally linked to the correct page of documentation, but copied the wrong example...

EDITING:

Copied (had to edit some) from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/access.html
Also, if RewriteMap is not supported you can chain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} domain.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} last-domain.net [NC]
RewriteRule   ^  -  [F]
```

instead. Probably has typos and errors, but the idea should be right.

### Description:

Redirect requests based on the Referer from which the request came, with different targets per Referer.

### Solution:

The following ruleset uses a map file to associate each Referer with a redirection target.

```
RewriteMap  deflector txt:/path/to/deflector.map

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
RewriteCond ${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}} =-
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_REFERER} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
RewriteCond ${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}|NOT-FOUND} !=NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule ^ ${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}} [R,L]
```

The map file lists redirection targets for each referer, or, if we just wish to redirect back to where they came from, a "-" is placed in the map:

```
##
##  deflector.map
##


http://badguys.example.com/bad/index.html    -
http://badguys.example.com/bad/index2.html   -
http://badguys.example.com/bad/index3.html   http://somewhere.example.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing is that resellerclub scam is not any visitor, but just a part of ilovevitaly.com which is affecting millions of Websites. They do not visit your Website, they just appears in your google analytics and badly affects your rankings and SEOs. It is trying to misguide you that it is recommended from google, so please be aware of these type of spam traffics which is nonhuman and operated by Russian organisation “Hosting Telesystems network”.
Same problem i was facing in my analytics and then i found this link and my problems is solved now. i am definitely sure the resellerclub scam refferal traffic would stop. Please follow the below article :-
http://techgnews.com/tips-tricks/resellerclub-scam/